# Is there a way to extract date along with link?

Tags: python, date, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping excel links from this [page](https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/3t945q76s?locale=en#release-items)

Is there a way to extract dates along with page links?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

base_url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu'

url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/3t945q76s?locale=en#release-items'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
b = []

page = 1
while True:
    pdf_urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('#release-items a[href$=".xls"]')]
    pprint(pdf_urls)
    b.append(pdf_urls)

    m = soup.select_one('a[rel="next"][href]')
    if m and m['href'] != '#':
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + m['href']).text, 'html.parser')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @larsks I was trying to use the class element for date, but the code was getting messy and I was unable to get it side by side with the link.

Comment: it is safer to get all `<tr>` and use `for`-loop to search date and links in every `<tr>` separatelly. If some row will not have date or links then you get `None` - using `zip()` you get date with links from next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some moment page gives rows without XLS and it is safer to get rows and later use `for`-loop to search link and date in every row separatelly. This way you can get which date doesn't have `xls`. Using `zip()` you can get date with link from next row.

Next pages use urls with `&page=2`, `&page=2`, etc. so you could use `&page={}` in URL to generate urls for next pages but this way you can't recognize last page and stop loop. Maybe using `status_code` in requests` you could recognized that you didn't get next page and then stop loop.

But there is better/simpler method - on page is button `Next` with link to next page and I use this to get next page.

Because in some moment there are not xls files on pages so I use this to stop loop earlier.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# --- functions ---

def get_data(soup):
    """Get links and dates for one page"""
    
    results = []
    
    all_rows = soup.select('#release-items tr')
    
    for row in all_rows:
        date = row.select_one('.date_uploaded').text
        pdf_url = row.select_one('a[href$=".xls"]')

        if pdf_url:
            pdf_url = pdf_url['href']
            results.append([date, pdf_url])
            print(date, pdf_url)
        else:
            print(date, "Can't find XLS")
            
    return results

# --- main ---

url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/3t945q76s?locale=en#release-items'

all_results = []

# - loop -

while True:
    print('url:', url)

    # get current page
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    # parse current page - get all needed data
    results = get_data(soup)
    if not results:  # there is no more XLS 
        break

    all_results += results
    
    # get link to next page
    url = soup.find('a', {'rel': 'next'})
    if not url or url['href'] == '#':  # there is no more pages
        break
    
    url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu' + url['href']

# - after loop -

print('--- results ---')
print('len:', len(all_results))
print('first:', all_results[0])
print('last :', all_results[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()`

```py
data = {}
for url, date in zip(soup.find_all("a", attrs={"data-label": "latest.xls"}), soup.find_all("td", class_="date_uploaded")):
    data[url['href']] = date.text
print(data)

#Output
{
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/gm80jj54x/rx914c582/latest.xls': 'Aug 12, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/sb397x16q/wm118b04x/latest.xls': 'Jul 10, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/g158c396h/5138k2221/latest.xls': 'Jun 11, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/w6634p60m/fx71b7035/latest.xls': 'May 12, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/q237jb60d/47429t84v/latest.xls': 'Apr  9, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/02871d57q/vx021z530/latest.xls': 'Mar 10, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/pz50hc74s/xw42ns32q/latest.xls': 'Feb 11, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/79408c82d/zg64v261j/latest.xls': 'Jan 10, 2020',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/1544c4419/xk81k173q/latest.xls': 'Dec 10, 2019',
'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/st74d522v/d217r356w/latest.xls': 'Nov  8, 2019'
}
```

Comment: How is s defined in `s.find`

Comment: its `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')` but for testing i kept it `s` instead of `soup`

Comment: Is there a way I could loop it through multiple pages? Like I did for extracting links in the code in the question. I tried something but I guess I am ending up with an infinite while loop.

Comment: some have only PDF what about those? keep it or ignore it?

Comment: I just want excel files. No PDFs or text files.

Comment: @rg03775 it is possible to run with many pages. Other pages use urls with `?locale=en&page=2#release-items` and there is `page=2`. So put code in loop and in every loop in `URL` change `page=2` to different number. And create `soup` inside loop.